# Cakephp 2.0 Session not storing find result of query any idea?

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I am using cakephp 2.0, for some reason I want to store the query result to session. Here is my code for config file.

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
'defaults' => 'cake',//php));
```

and I have included the Session component in app controller, now what I want is

```
$tender_data = $this->Tender->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Tender.id' => $tender_ids)));
$this->Session->write('tender_data', $tender_data);
```

but when i read

```
debug($this->Session->read('tender_data'));
```

it displays false but if I manually store data like

```
$this->Session->write('result',array('Rajeev'=>array('profile'=>'IT','Job'=>'SE'),'Deepak','Aklesh','Pradeep'));
```

and read its works fine any idea is my result is too much to store in session or what??

solution invited

Comment: Do you sure that `find` actually returns array and doesn't fail?

Comment: yes i have cross checked result is returing, well for my purpose now i am using cache instead of session for work around.